# Handler not working as planned

Tags: android, timer, handler, postdelayed

```
try 
{              
          //got input from asset that's not a problem

           JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());

            JSONArray m_jArry1 = obj.getJSONArray("check");
            int j=0,i,k=0;

            while(j<m_jArry1.length()) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = m_jArry1.getJSONObject(j);
                JSONArray m_jArry = jsonObject.getJSONArray("formules");

                ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(m_jArry.length());
                for (i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) {
                    list.add(i);
                }

                Collections.shuffle(list);

              //shuffled the list for random generation of questions and answer 
              // so that's not a problem too.    


                for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

                    JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(list.get(i));
                    formula_value = jo_inside.getString("ques");
                    url_value = jo_inside.getString("ans");



          /*I want to read question and answer from formula_value &
            url_value each time and wait for 6 seconds until the next set arrives... 
            So I used Handler to make it wait for 6 seconds which isn't working ..         
            but  it's going to the last value  directly .*/

                    handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {


                            textView.setText(formula_value);


                            editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {


                //using this so that there is an action only when done is pressed .
                                @Override
                                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                                    if(actionId== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                                        //Clear focus here from edittext
                                        editText.clearFocus();
                                    }
                                    if(editText.getText().equals(url_value)){
                                        total++;
                                        textView1.setText("Correct");
                             //display correct if right 
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        textView1.setText("Wrong");
                             //display wrong if wrong
                                    }

                                    return false;
                                }
                            });

                        }


                },6000);
```

here i have given 6 seconds .. what really happens is that the plain textView is displayed for 6 seconds and then the last question gets appeared on the screen ..

```
                    Log.d("For and url is ",formula_value+" and   "+url_value);
                }


                j++;
            }

        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

see the log: they get logged quickly without waiting .. 
 Do help me pls
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is due to you are not updating your value in handler's runnable. **Handler.Postdelay not pausing the loop. The loop is being executed. and your value is being updated prior to 6 seconds.** And when your 6 seconds ends you will get last value always as your loop is executed.

One more thing I observed is that You are using nested loop here. I suggest you to use **recursion** in this condition. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem thank you .. I was using a for loop which is a big mistake. I now have a big doubt on how to stop the handler. I used

```
    mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

                or

    mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

and did all possible steps to stop the process. nothing is working out, there is an infinite loop execution. I don't know how to stop it :(

C here bro :      [handler.removecallbacks not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871429/handler-removecallbacks-not-working)